# How to include/require a php file from c/c++ php extension passing variables to userspace scope?

Tags: php, c

First i need import a file from PHP_FUNCTION(), and passing to imported php file some variables from C function into userspace.

Example:

include_a_file.c

```c
PHP_FUNCTION(include_a_php_file)
{
  zval *var_to_userspace;
  char *str;
  str = "string send to userspace";
  ZVAL_STRING(var_to_userspace, str, 0);

  php_require_once("a_file.php"); // <-- how to?
}
```

a_file.php

```php
<?php
  print "<pre>";
  vardump($var_to_userspace);
  print "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `zend_compile_string()`:

```
zval nop;
ZVAL_STRINGL(&nop, "return ;", 8, 0);
zend_compile_string(&nop, "NOP" TSRMLS_CC);
```

This will return you pointer to `zend_op_array` struct, which will be holding Zend opcodes for your code.
So you can just dump these opcodes once and create `zend_op_array` struct in your program yourself.

Comment: it's same that eval()? wouldn't be slow?

Comment: Do you have an example using zend_compile_string?

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.x

```
zval nop;
ZVAL_STRINGL(&nop, "return ;", 8, 0);
zend_compile_string(&nop, "NOP");
```